# Setting up a SONAR Post Build Action in Jenkins (Maven Job)

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar 3.5.1, Jekins Sonar Plugin 2.1. Plugin is installed in Jenkins.
I have added the Post Build Action with Sonar and default settings.
I got this error at building-time.

I am not sure what to do. Do I have to modify the pom.xml?

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin
groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories 
[local (/export/home/tpbuild/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org
/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for   
prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, 
org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/export/home/tpbuild
/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following lines to the settings.xml configuration file should fix this issue :

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure Manage jenkins-> configure system meanse you need to provide sonarqube server details,database details and sonar runner details in jenkins

you make sure sonar plugun must be installed in jenkins.

Comment: I tried to edit this to be a little clearer, but I can't actually tell what you mean, so I can't clarify it.